# My app showing error while starting new Activity under Pop-up menu in android

Tags: android

I am creating a listview in one of tab fragment using holder and in that listview I am putting a button to pop-up options like share, show coupon etc.Once user will click any of these option a new activity need to be started.
When I am clicking "show Coupon" option in menu pop-up to start new activity which is basically showing image of coupon, my application gets crashed saying "Unfortunately app is stopped"
I am sharing adapter and coupon activity code and menu_list.xml. Please help why new activity is not getting started.
1. My Adapter Class:

```
package com.trillbit.retail.activity;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.media.Image;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.view.ContextThemeWrapper;
import android.widget.PopupMenu;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.widget.ToggleButton;

import com.trillbit.retail.R;

/**
 * Created by shashikant.burnwal on 12-29-2016.
 */

public class PlaceAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Place>{
    final Context mContext;
    int mLayoutResourceID;
    Place mData[]=null;

    public PlaceAdapter(Context context, int resource, Place[] data) {
        super(context, resource, data);
        this.mContext = context;
        this.mLayoutResourceID = resource;
        this.mData = data;
    }

    @Override
    public Place getItem(int position) {
        return super.getItem(position);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View row=convertView;
        PlaceHolder holder=null;
        //row initialization
        if(row==null){
            LayoutInflater inflater=LayoutInflater.from(mContext);
            row=inflater.inflate(mLayoutResourceID,parent,false);
            holder=new PlaceHolder();
            holder.nameView=(TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.nameTextView);
            holder.offerView=(TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.zipcodeTextView);
            holder.imageView=(ImageView)row.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
            holder.menuButton=(ImageButton)row.findViewById(R.id.menu_button);
            row.setTag(holder);



        }else{
            holder=(PlaceHolder)row.getTag();
        }
        Place place=mData[position];
        holder.nameView.setText(place.mPlace);
        holder.offerView.setText(String.valueOf(place.mOffer));
        int resID=mContext.getResources().getIdentifier(place.mImage,"drawable",mContext.getPackageName());
        holder.imageView.setImageResource(resID);


        //menuButton Activity

        holder.menuButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                Context wrapper = new ContextThemeWrapper(getContext(), R.style.popupMenuStyle);
                PopupMenu popup = new PopupMenu(wrapper,view);

                popup.getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_list,popup.getMenu());
                popup.show();

                popup.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {

                        switch(item.getItemId()){
                            case R.id.share:
                                return true;
                            case R.id.show_coupon:
                                Intent intent = new Intent();
                                intent.setClass(getContext(), CouponActivity.class);
                                Bundle bunde = new Bundle();
                                bunde.putString("coupon","Here is Coupon");
                                intent.putExtras(bunde);
                                getContext().startActivity(intent);
                                return true;
                            case R.id.like:
                                return true;
                            default:
                                return true;

                        }

                    }
                });

            }
        });


        return row;

    }

    private static class PlaceHolder{
        TextView nameView;
        TextView offerView;
        ImageView imageView;
        ImageButton menuButton;

    }
}
```

2. My New Activity:

```
package com.trillbit.retail.activity;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.trillbit.retail.R;

/**
 * Created by shashikant.burnwal on 01-04-2017.
 */

public class CouponActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private ImageView image1;
    private Button closeButton1;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_coupon);
        Bundle extras=getIntent().getExtras();
        if(extras!=null){
            String detailValue=extras.getString("coupon");
            if(detailValue!=null){
                Toast.makeText(this,detailValue,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }

        image1=(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.couponImage);
        closeButton1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.closeButton);
        closeButton1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                finish();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

3. Menu_list.xml:

   [

   ```
   <item
       android:id="@+id/like"
       android:title="@string/like"
       app:showAsAction="ifRoom|withText"
       android:visible="true"/>


   <item android:id="@+id/share"
         android:title="@string/share"
         app:showAsAction="ifRoom|withText"
       android:visible="true"/>

   <item android:id="@+id/show_coupon"
         android:title="@string/show_coupon"
         app:showAsAction="ifRoom|withText"
         android:visible="true"/>
   ```

   ][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uYGCP.png)
4. I am also attaching image of how my app look:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) Make sure you have added the CouponActivity  as an activity in your manifest file.

2) When you are launching a new activity from a *non-activity* class, you need to add a flag *Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK* before launching the intent.

```
holder.menuButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            Context wrapper = new ContextThemeWrapper(getContext(), R.style.popupMenuStyle);
            PopupMenu popup = new PopupMenu(wrapper,view);

                popup.getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_list,popup.getMenu());
            popup.show();

            popup.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {

                    switch(item.getItemId()){
                        case R.id.share:
                            return true;
                        case R.id.show_coupon:
                            Intent intent = new Intent();
                            intent.setClass(getContext(), CouponActivity.class);
                            Bundle bunde = new Bundle();
                            bunde.putString("coupon","Here is Coupon");
                            intent.putExtras(bunde);
                            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK); //Needed when starting an activity from a non-activity class
                            getContext().startActivity(intent);
                            return true;
                        case R.id.like:
                            return true;
                        default:
                            return true;

                    }

                }
            });

        }
    });
```

Comment: point 2 solved my problem. Thanks a lot!! You saved my day, was struggling since 2 days on it.

Comment: Thought so :) Glad to help :)